# Python data transfer via bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

i need to send data computed by **python** program to my **lego mindstorms nxt2.0**  robot via **bluetooth**. how is this possible? what tools do i require?

Comment: Normally bluetooth will create a transparent serial port. You don't need nothing special for bluetooth, but [serial io for python](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html).

Comment: First use google and then if you can't find answer ask there.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do the same thing.  There is a information file about the blue tooth communication at [the mindstorms web site.](http://us.mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/files/default.aspx)  If you are using python 3.3 or newer you can use [sockets](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) to communicate.  I still have not gotten this to work.  If you are not using python 3.3 you could use pybluez.